# Request Permission Android >= 6.0 in Cordova APP

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions

I would like to request permission at runtime in a Cordova App in the method OnCreate() into public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to request runtime permission by modifying the Cordova activity in Java? You could just use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to request the appropriate permissions from the Javascript layer.

Comment: great plugin. thanks!

Comment: @DaveAlden How can use this plugin in my custom plugin

Comment: @Bahu either add it as a [dependency](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#dependency) and use it as-is, or take what you want from the source code

Comment: Ho okay thank you i'll do...